# Issues getting application approved

Tags: ios-appstore

We build and sell a SaaS application, our clients have asked us to produce apps which allow this application to be accessed from their phones.

We have developed and submitted to Apple a version for the iPhone and this has been rejected as it should be distributed as a custom B2B application via the "Volume Purchase Program".  Having reviewed the "Volume Purchase Program" this is far from ideal due to a wide range of reasons:

- Clients want the iPhone version of the app for personal phones, business phones are largely Blackberrys.
- As our clients don't already have an account it will be necessary for them to register if their meet the requirements of the program or are able to due to internal policies.
- It will then be necessary for the organisation to purchase (a free app) and manage the distribution of the app internally via a spreadsheet.
- We will also have the overhead of granting additional clients access to the app.

Has anyone got any suggestion to over come these issues?

Comment: If you don't get a response here, you may want to ask over at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Programming and app development topics are off topic here on Ask Different. A better place to ask would be on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you go down the 3rd party App Store route.  We use [Nukona](https://www.nukona.com/) (part of Symantec) here at work.

With one account you can manage all your clients, have multiple apps and limit apps to groups (clients), and if you expand your development past iOS, then it also supports BB and Android.